# React Icons Sizing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I imported some React icons and I don't know how to make them bigger since they are so small, anyone know how I can make their size bigger?

I tried with giving them a class and trying to adjust the height and width but it did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use CSS to change the font-size property

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using the react-icons package (https://npm.im/react-icons), you can pass a `size` prop to the component:

```
import { FaBeer } from "react-icons/fa";

function Question() {
  return (
    <h3>
      {" "}
      Lets go for a <FaBeer size={50} />?{" "}
    </h3>
  );
}
```